# Add custom button on keyboard for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I want to add custom button "Done" on return key. I am using keyboard notification methods for adding button. But it do not work smoothly for iOs7. Custom done button is visible after some delay.

Comment: You can use `textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;` instead adding custom button.

Comment: OMG. you were adding "Done" button manually??

Comment: @AdilSoomro He is not adding Done manually, I guess he is trying to add buttons on top of the keyboard.

Comment: may be BSKeyBoardController will help you for that.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add buttons on top of the keyboard. Its working fine for iOS6 and 5. But not for iOS7

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the docs for `inputAccessoryView` ... it's probably what you want.

Comment: No. I want my own "Done" button instead of default done button. Its working fine for iOS5 and 6. But due to delay for keyboard animation, there is an issue with iOS7. Can any one tell me how to change default keyboard animation? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Add a `UIToolBar` with some y axis as out of bottom of the screen. then on `UITextField` of `UITextView` select, bring that toolbar with 0.25 sec animation on `startEditing` event of the `textfield`. Final `y` axis of the toolbar will be just above the keypad.

Comment: I have to use keyboard did show notification. Because in Keyboard will show function, there is window having no keyboard. And due to that method it is displaying done button after some delay.